# Replacing all occurrences of a string within a file

Tags: unix

I'm producing many files with numeric fields. All the fields end with . Like 1234. 
I need to Replace all occurrences of '.,' with a ','in all files

Comment: do you mean there are litteral single-quote chars "surrounding" your data fields?

Comment: Can you please include in your question (i.e. hit the "edit" link under your question) a sample of your input data, a sample of your intended output, and whatever code you have written so far to attempt to solve your problem yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all the files are in the same dir, AND you're using an new-ish  `gnu sed` that supports the `-i` (inplace) optin , you can do

```
   cd /path/to/dataDir
   for file in * ; do
      sed  -i 's/\([0-9]\)\.,/\1./g' "$f"
   done
```

If you're using Mac OSX, you can either supply a file extension to the `-i` option like

```
      sed -i".bak" ....
```

or indicate "overwrite existing" with

```
    sed -i""
```

If you're in an vendored-unix environment, you may need to manage the output yourself. Then you can replace inner-loop with

```
      sed s/\([0-9]\)\.,/\1./g' "$f" > "$f".new && /bin/mv "$f".new "$f"
```

IHTH